# Issue with strftime (python)

Tags: python, strftime

I try to send data on Mosquitto Broker and add this same data on SQLite
This is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlite3
import logging

class Photos:
    def __init__(self):
            #Connection a la basse de donnees sqlite3
            self.db = sqlite3.connect('/home/pi/FlowerPower.db')
            #Preparation d'un objet cursor qui va executer les futures requetes SQL sur la base de donnees
            self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

            logging.basicConfig(filename='subscribeFP.log',level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

    def traitement(self, msg, numSonde):
            try:
                    #Convertit le message poste par le publisher de byte a string
                    queryArgs = str(msg.payload)
                    #Variable nom de la sonde
                    nomSonde = str(numSonde[2])
                    #Prepare la requete SQL pour la table photo
                    queryText = "INSERT INTO photos(sonde, date, photos) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (nomSonde, strftime('%%d-%%m-%%Y %%H:%%%M:%%S','now','localtime'), queryArgs)
                    #Execute la requete SQL sur la BDD
                    self.cursor.execute(str(queryText))
                    #Commit pour etre sur que la requete SQL est effectuee
                    self.db.commit()
                    #Code d'exception
            except sqlite3.Error as e:
                    self.logging.error('Erreur Sqlite3: ' + str(e))
                    #Retour en arrière si il y a une erreur (proprietes ACID)
                    self.db.rollback()
```

When I send data with a `mosquitto_pub` I have this error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mosquitto.py", line 720, in loop
rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mosquitto.py", line 961, in loop_read
   rc = self._packet_read()
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mosquitto.py", line 1360, in _packet_read
   rc = self._packet_handle()
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mosquitto.py", line 1775, in _packet_handle
     return self._handle_publish()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mosquitto.py", line 1888, in _handle_publish
    self.on_message(self, self._userdata, message)
  File "insertionBdd.py", line 37, in on_message
photos.traitement(msg, numSonde)
  File "/home/pi/photosFP.py", line 22, in traitement
    queryText = "INSERT INTO photos(sonde, date, photos) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (nomSonde, strftime('%%d-%%m-%%Y %%H:%%%M:%%S','now','localtime'), queryArgs)
 NameError: global name 'strftime' is not defined
```

I don't understand why I have this error and I have already try to add: "from datetime importe datetime"
My other script, run with `strftime` but there are not this problem...
Somebody can help me, please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like the message says, you haven't defined `strftime`, you've only defined `datetime`.

`strftime` is a method of a datetime object. However, you seem to be calling it as a standalone function, passing it some strings: that's not at all how it works. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but it looks like you want to get the current time and format that. So, you need to actually call the relevant methods:

```
datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

I'm also not sure what `'localtime'` is doing in your code, or why you doubled the percent signs.

Comment: google brought me to this answered question, I believe your answer may be what I need.  I cannot figure out what module I must import to be able to use your line of code though.  Mind filling me in?

Comment: As the OP mentioned in his question, `from datetime import datetime`.

Comment: I tried that and get ImportError: cannot import name 'datetime'

Comment: You have a file in your local directory called "datetime.py", rename it. Please ask a new question for any other issues.